# 'End of file expected' when appending to json file

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I'm relatively new to python / using JSONs and I'm having an issue.

I'm trying to add 200 of my tweets to a json file. here is my code that does this :

```
def process_or_store(tweet):
with open('baileighsTweets.json', 'a') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(tweet._json, indent=4))
    f.close()

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items(200):
    process_or_store(tweet)
```

This code runs fine, and adds my tweets to a json file, with each tweet being a json object. however, an error occurs with one of my objects in the json file :

[picture with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn4Ec.png)

[same code on a different line, no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAKiy.png)

it appears to be a very basic syntax issue but I'm confused about why it happened - my code adds to the json file, I don't do it manually, so I don't understand why I received an 'end of file expected' error, and I don't how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for your help/suggestions guys!

Comment: *my code adds to the json file* – yes, that's exactly the problem. The JSON file should contain only one JSON string. You're trying to store multiple in one file. It looks like you want an array, but you'll have to create it first and write it to the file once when it contains everything you want.

Comment: when you say 'JSON string' do you mean for e.g having (at the start) of my JSON file "myTweets" : {and then all my tweets here}?
also I will try the second thing you mentioned, thanks for the help!

Comment: In other words, you keep writing completely new objects to the file so it becomes `{"a":1}{"b":2}{"c":3}` and so on which is obviously invalid JSON. If you want multiple objects in the same file they must be inside an array.

Answer (score -1):

It would have been good if you had attached the json file along the question. I feel there might be syntax issue like missing "," or the "}" braces. You can use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json and try to understand where the real issue is. Hope this helps you.

Comment: see i thought so too, but then I thought that that wouldn't make sense, I didn't add anything to the file myself, my code did. all the code is identical except for that one weird error. thanks for sharing that link btw! I've never heard of it but I'm sure its gonna be super useful :)